# How can I put image in Image View in Android Studio For Android Noutgat and below

Tags: android, xml, android-imageview

I have image view on my project . It cant work Android Noutgat and below . But It can work For Android 8.0 and above . How Can I solve .

**MyActivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/Color_white"
    >
    
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/backroundlegend"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And When I delete imageView then It can works for Android Noutgat and below

Comment: for imageviews u should use android:src and not android:background
either way, could u post the error u are getting? and what do u mean by deleting?

Comment: I did use src but It  still cant work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android versions has nothing to do with your case.

When you set an image to an `ImageView`, you need Image loader libraries like [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso), [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco), [Coil](https://github.com/coil-kt/coil) etc to load the image programmatically, if you don't set image like this, either the image is shown in very low quality or most of the time, image doesn't load. You can use either one but Glide is the most popular I believe.

What you've to do is give the `ImageView` an ID, access it in the Java/Kotlin class file this layout is associated with and set the image to it with any of these libraries.

But first, you've to implement the library in your project. See the implementation instructions on these libraries' page I've linked above.

Then, give the ID `imageView` as

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    ...
    />
```

Then, access it in the Java/Kotlin file as

```
//Kotlin
val imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
//Java
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

Then, set your image as

```
//this is the Context here for activity, use context or requireContext() in Fragment.
Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.backgroundlegend).into(imageView)
```

After this, your image will appear. Remember this, when you set svg and drawables, you don't need to load the image programmatically but when you use images like png, jpg/jpeg, you've to use image loaders. Futher, you can play with `scaleType` property of `ImageView` to adjust the image in the `ImageView`'s view bounds.

Comment: as much as your answer has covered all the topic, Glide and other libraries are best known for loading images online, if the pic is in his drawable folder, he can just load it from the XML as it is with no need for an external library

Comment: thx it can work . When I use   android:background="@drawable/backroundlegend" then it fill parent in width but When I use Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.backgroundlegend).into(imageView) ıt cant fill how can ı solve

Comment: @MahmoudOmara If the images have been resized in the needed format of ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi then that can work. But, if the images consist of only one hd or better version in nodpi folder, then Android can't select the correct version of the image to load as per the device and it doesn't work. And then the need of image loaders arise.

Comment: @ogi_plus If you want to fill width, try setting the `scaleType` as `centreCrop`. You can also set `adjustViewBounds` to true to adjust the height of the `ImageView` as the height of the image and it will fill the width. So image of any dimension will always be full on width and full on height, no extra blank borders of the `ImageView`.